Test if function exported from inside a hook gets called
I'm trying to test that a function, which is defined inside of a hook, is called in a component that uses that hook/function. I'm familiar with mocking simple modules/functions, but this scenario has me confused as I don't know how to mock only a single returned function from that hook without losing all of the other functions/logic in that hook, which I don't want to mock.
Let's say I have a hook that looks like this:
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useSomeHook = () => {
  const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState();
  const [someOtherValue, setSomeOtherValue] = useState();

  // a bunch of other logic in here...

  return {
    someValue,
    setSomeValue,
    someOtherValue,
    setSomeOtherValue,
  }
}

Then I have a function component that uses that hook:
export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { setSomeValue } = useSomeHook();

  return (<button onClick={() => setSomeValue('hey')}>hello</button>);
}

I'd like to be able to test that setSomeValue gets called when the button is clicked.
const mockSetSomeValue = jest.fn();

jest.mock('./useSomeHook.js', () => {
  const actual = jest.requireActual('./useSomeHook.js');
  return {
    ...actual,
    // This won't work because now everything else inside of useSomeHook is missing and other tests I have in this file will fail
    useSomeHook: () => ({
      setSomeValue: mockSetSomeValue,
    })
  }
});

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  it('should call setSomeValue when button is clicked', () => {
    render(<SomeComponent />);
    // fire event to click button
    expect(mockSetSomeValue).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hey');
  });
});

Is something like this possible? Thanks!

You might be able to use https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/ to test your hook. However, when testing a component that uses the hook, you really shouldn't be testing the implementation details of the hook itself, you should be testing the behavior of your component. EG, in this case, you should check that after you click the button, on the next render that outputs the value of someValue somewhere in the DOM, you query that text and expect that it finds the right element eg (assuming you use Testing Library) expect(await queryByText('hey')).toBeInTheDocument()

Derek is correct, trying to test at that level of granularity is going to be fragile

@Derek and @Jared Who said anything will be shown on the DOM??? If you don't limit the question to your personal assumptions, then my answer is the better solution.

Generally I try and follow the philosophy of not testing implementation details, but I have a function that gets called with a bunch of arguments and I want to check that the expected values were provided to that function. I was trying to provide a really simplified example and to @Top-Master point nothing gets written to the DOM in my actual code.

The OP already knows how to unit-test, i.e. mock everything, but like many others, he noticed the limits and complexity of unit-test(s) vs integeration-test(s).
Hence, try integeration-testing instead, like:
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

// ...

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const { setSomeValue } = useSomeHook();
    setSomeValue('my-default');
  });

  it('should call setSomeValue when button is clicked', () => {
    // Dummy.
    const { getByTestId } = render(<SomeComponent />);
    // Without changing while render.
    const { someValue } = useSomeHook();
    expect(someValue()).toEqual('my-default');
    // With trigger.
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('id'));

    // Actual test.
    expect(someValue()).toEqual('hey');
  });
});

Much simpler and if you follow the above comment-style, then you later know exactly what does what.
Forget Uncle-Sam's book that limits you to one assert per test, since if you never assert the dummy, then you'll later search hours for why the actual-test is failing.
